# Mnemonics for learning Greek alphabet?

Tags: writing-system, electronic-resources, greek, physical-resources

I'm looking for resources that use mnemonics for the [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet), so I can learn the writing system in less time.

I would prefer a printed or printable resources (ideally small), but an electronic resource is also fine if nothing in print can be found.

I found the YouTube video [Greek Alphabet: It's Easy To Learn The Greek Alphabet With Mnemonics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V4tc-5Kuh4) by Anthony Metivier, but this describes a method (a [memory palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_loci)) that you still need to "fill" with your own mnemonics. Since his own mnemonics don't work well for me, I am looking for something else.

In addition, it needs to be a resource that focuses on Modern Greek, not [Koiné Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek).

Answer (score 3):

Mathematical notation is a home to a great number of mnemonics, though they are mostly useful if one is fluent in mathematics, physics, statistics, or a related field. For example:

- Capital sigma, short for sum, is used in sum notation. Capital pi is used in the much rarer product notation.
- Capital delta is used for change in elementary mechanics and elsewhere.
- In a first university level course in analysis one meets epsilon-delta proofs, where epsilon stands for error and (non-capital) delta stands for difference. Both are used more generally for small quantities.
- Rho (that looks like p) is often used for pressure.
- Alpha, beta and gamma are commonly used for angles, even at gymnasium level or in middle school.

Not all of the Greek letters are used regular - capital alpha is not common for obvious reasons (though one Greek lecturer once used it for fun), and I do not think I have ever seen a iota or an omicron in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the fact that the Greek and Latin alphabets have many common characters. Also you could see Greek words and their pronunciation(this helped me memorize the cyrillic alphabet a lot.)

Comment: How would that help people whose native language does not use an alphabet, let alone the Latin alphabet?

Comment: My answer was tailored to you. Now if someone's native language doesn't use the Latin alphabet if they don't know how to speak English they wouldn't be able to read this question anyway...